# Maximal ideals and the projective Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

*This is a simple question, but it's one of those things that I've been thinking about so much that I've just kind of lost where I am and need some explicit reference.*

One of the main corollaries of the affine Nullstellensatz (i.e. that $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I)) = \sqrt{I}$) is that maximal ideals in $R=k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ are in bijective correspondence with points in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$.
In all (but one -- see below) of the literature I've read that talks of the projective Nullstellensatz, there is no mention of what maximal ideals of $R$ correspond to, just what prime ideals in general correspond to.
I assumed that, if there were a similar fact, then I would have found it somewhere.

But after some thinking we see that points in projective space correspond to lines through the origin in affine space, which are irreducible affine varieties, but not affine *points*.
Thus points in projective space correspond to (prime) ideals in $R$ coming from lines through the origin.

In the opposite direction, maximal ideals in $R$ correspond to points in affine space, and so *can't* correspond directly to points in projective space **but** each point in affine space uniquely determines a point in projective space, since it uniquely determines a line through the origin and that point.
So it seems like there should be some maximal ideal/points in projective space correspondence, and one way kind of seems almost clear to me, but the other doesn't so much.

**In essence** could anybody please explain the correspondence between maximal ideals properly contained in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ and points of projective space.
We know that all maximal ideals are of the form $(x_0-a_0,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$, and these correspond to the point $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ in affine space.
Is there an equally nice formulation for the projective case?

Here is the one reference that I could find:

[image]

Comment: We always have a morphism $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{P}^n$. Thus, any maximal ideal other than $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ gives you a point in $\mathbb{P}^n$, the correspondence is not one-to-one, but still nice. Notice that the multiplicative group acts naturally by multiplying all the $x_i$'s by the same number on $R$ and all maximal ideals in a single orbit goes to the same point in projective space and vice versa.

Comment: I was just curious where the excerpt above comes from. Thanks!

Comment: @mwmjp https://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=22003

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore... I was trying to look for the notes on the Zürich University webpage and I found the scheme-theoretic algebraic geometry notes from Joseph Ayoub, but I think your screenshot is from other notes, right? I couldn't find it there.

Comment: @ElíasGuisado This is from "Quotients in algebraic and symplectic geometry" by Victoria Hoskins, which seems to be available at https://silo.tips/download/quotients-in-algebraic-and-symplectic-geometry , but this is also Theorem 4.4 in what seems to be an updated version of these notes, called "Geometric Invariant Theory and Symplectic Quotients" (by the same author), which can currently be found at https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/hoskins/GITnotes.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. There is a map from $\mathbb{A}^{n+1} - \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}^n$ for any $n$, but this is not the way we realize the co-ordinate ring, and the construction one would get if one tried to blow up points into lines in this quotient would not be the affine variety corresponding to some subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ but the pullback of the tautological bundle onto this variety.

The real maps to consider are the co-ordinate maps: $\mathbb{A}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ that make $\mathbb{P}^n$ a variety. These induce isomorphisms between $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{P}^n - \{(x_1:\dots : x_{n+1}) | x_i = 0\})$, and this is how you prove the correspondence between maximal ideals that do not contain the trivial homogeneous ideal $R(X)_+$ (which obviously cannot be included) and points in $\mathbb{P}^n$, you use these homeomorphisms.

Comment: So given some maximal ideal $m$ not containing $R(X)_+$, this corresponds to some maximal ideal $\hat{m}$ of $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ not containing $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$. So we know that there exists some $x_i$ such that $\hat{m}$ doesn't contain $(x_i)$... and then where do we go?

Comment: why can we not use a proof that goes something like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405195/proof-of-the-correspondence-between-maximal-ideals-and-points-in-affine-space ?

Comment: Then we take the map $\phi: \mathbb{P}^n - \{x_i = 0\} \to \mathbb{A}^n$ that sends $(a_1: \dots : a_{n+1}) \to (a_1/a_i, \dots, a_{n+1}/a_i)$ which induces an isomorphism of coordinate rings on some open set homeomorphic to $mathbb{A}^n$... And from here it should be very obvious to you. This is exactly how they want you to prove it in that link.

Comment: How do we deal with patching the affine patches together though? That is, if some $x$ has $x_i,x_j\neq0$, then how do we know that the maximal ideal given by looking at $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus\{x_i=0\}$ is the same as that given by looking at $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus\{x_j=0\}$?

Comment: Further, the Nullstellensatz tells us that **all** maximal ideals of the polynomial ring $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ are of the form $(x_0-a_0,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$, but this is not homogeneous. So how can there exist maximal homogeneous ideals?

Comment: We start with a maximal ideal in the projective co-ordinate ring and all we want to do is show that it's vanishing set corresponds to a point. You will not get an unambiguous choice of affine maximal ideal. There are two different rings in play when it comes to projective space. There is a graded co-ordinate ring on projective space and there are the affine co-ordinate rings.

Answer (score 1):

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1643498/346324

This answer is for the analogous problem in Vakil but is more explicit than what has been given already and looks similar to the affine situation.

Comment: I don't think this can be count as an answer. It's just a comment.

Comment: @user26857 I agree. It's a very useful comment, but still a comment...

Comment: I'm trying to say that question above has already been asked and answered in the link that I gave...