# Cones of max-Spec

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $R=k\oplus R_1\oplus R_2\oplus \ldots$ be a graded commutative ring that's finitely generated by elements of positive degree. If $M$ is a finitely generated graded $R$-module then $$V(M):=\{\mathfrak{m}\in \text{max-Spec} R: M_\mathfrak{m}\neq 0\}\cup \{R_+\}.$$ I am reading this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702654v2.pdf) and they mention that $V(M)$ is a $k$-rational cone (I have slightly changed notation from their exposition,  but I hopefully have extracted the major ingredients).  Note that since $M$ is finitely generated, $$V(M)=\{\mathfrak{m}\in \text{max-Spec} R: \mathfrak{m}\supseteq \text{ann}_R M\}\cup \{R_+\}.$$ Now let $$\text{Supp}_R^+M:=\{\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Proj}R: M_{\mathfrak{p}}\neq 0\},$$then the authors say  this set determines and is determined by $V(M)$. I was wondering how this correspondence works.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** One thing to note is that Supp$_R^+M=V^+(M)$ where $$V^+(M):=\{\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Proj} R: \mathfrak{p}\supseteq \text{ann}_R M\}$$ since $M$ is finitely generated. Also, ann$_RM$ is a homogeneous ideal, since $M$ is a graded $R$-module. So I'm asking how is the following correspondence established?: $$(V(I)\cap \text{max-Spec}R)\cup\{R_+\}\leftrightarrow V^+(I),$$ where $I$ is a homogeneous ideal of $R$.

Comment: I think you can assume $I=(0)$. Then could find something useful in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1404255/121097).